# can't change channel of my wifi interface using aircrack

Tags: wifi, ubuntu-12.04, aircrack-ng

Whenever I try to listen to a specific wifi channel using airodump I got : `fixed channel wlan0: -1`
I try to change the channel but it's always -1!

I use Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: I think this question better asked on http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: http://trac.aircrack-ng.org/ticket/742

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have to do is execute `ifconfig wlan0 down`

make sure you are not connected to any wireless network, try:
`airodump-ng -<the channel you want> --bssid<the wireless network you want> mon0`

If it doesn't work, try:

- `ifconfig wlan0 down` then
- `ifconfig mon0 down` then
- `iwconfig mon0 mode monitor` then
- `ifconfig wlan0 up` then
- `ifconfig mon0 up` and try to sniff now.